# Can I "stack up" selectors using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know "selectors" is the wrong term, but I can't remember it :P

I have this script:

```
$(function() {
   //checkbox
   $("#checkbox2, .akslabel").click(function(){
    $("#scrollwrap").toggleClass('highlight');
   });
});
```

Is it ok to stack up the selectors like that? Or should I re-write it for each one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use as many selectors as you want combined with a `,` ([the multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)) and bind the same anonymous function to them all, which is what your example does.

There's nothing wrong with this, it's cleaner/more concise code.

So can you "stack" selectors? Yes, think of them as waffles, very delicious waffles, with bacon.

Comment: nothing... they just go by themselves.  Maybe some whipped cream or powdered sugar (http://www.suikerfee.be/wafels/brusselse/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use a comma-separator for binding events to multiple elements with different classnames/id's/etcetera.

If it isn't working, you have class "akslabel", might want to change that to "asklabel"...?

Comment: Thanks, actually it's in Norwegian so the word "accept" is "aksept" hence, "akslabel" the label pertaining to my "accept check box" :)

Comment: Aha so that makes sense :) ... and I love Royksopp!

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, it's even better then splitting. Why duplicate code?